# Get data from children class

Tags: javascript

I have
`<span class="blnc-ind"></span>`

and

`<a class="blnc-ind__income" href="/profile/money">1,13 $</a>` inside of it

I want to get data of

`<a class="blnc-ind__income" href="/profile/money">1,13 $</a>`

that is only `1,13 $` without any code

I was tried to use this command:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('blnc-ind__income');
```

but console show it only this way:

```
[ <a class="blnc-ind__income" href="/profile/money">1,13 $</a> ]
```

Please, help me to solve this problem

Comment: use `document.getElementsByClassName('blnc-ind__income')[0].innerHTML `to get the text inside the element

Comment: @Andreas Why  won't it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('blnc-ind__income')[0].textContent;
```

This function returns to you an array not a single element, so you need to get your element by the indexing.And then to get the content of that element

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

Difference between `textContent` and `innerHTML`

**textContent** uses straight text, does not parse HTML, and is faster.
**innerHTML** parses content as HTML and takes longer.